# Add Show Desktop Option to Gnome Pie

Tags: unity, show-desktop, gnome-pie

There is no default option for this. I have tried binding an icon to keyboard shortcut super+d but this only works occasionally. Is there a command I can have the icon run that would show desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Control ("Ctrl") + Super (the "Windows" key) + "D".

This minimizes all currently-open windows, allowing you to see the desktop... Press the key combination again to restore all of the windows.